How to defer inline CSS?
Is there any valid possibility to defer the <style></style> code?
Background:
I created a custom crawler, which loads a page with headless Chrome, with defined viewport settings. The crawler evaluates all existing CSS (links and inline), and creates two CSS parts, first as critical CSS, second as uncritical.
Now I have two CSS parts and want to defer the uncritical part as <style>.
I think about a way like it can be done with JS
<script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()


There is no way to do that directly with the style element, it offers no attribute for that. But you can of course dynamically create a style element at the desired time, and then set its content.

while there is no defer in css, you can use fetch
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  fetch("uncritical.css")
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((css) => {
      const style = document.createElement("style");
      style.textContent = css;
      document.head.appendChild(style);
    });
});

or, you can do this.
<link rel="preload" href="uncritical.css" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="uncritical.css"></noscript>


As I mentioned, I have no file, only inline <style> tag
